# Efficiently access either of two Delphi datamodules with same dataobject names

Tags: delphi, datamodule

I have an ugly situation where I need two datamodules (TDMA, TDMB) in a Delphi app. Each datamodule has the same data object names (queries, tables, etc.) but from a different component set (TZQuery, TADOQuery). I need this because I want to support multiple databases but not all databases are supported by my component suite. Which datamodule I need to access is determined by the DBFlag boolean variable. Besides having separate nearly identical code segments for each data access, is there some more efficient way?

If I could set a global datamodule variable like DMG to either DMA or DMB based on DBFlag then my code could reference DMG instead of DMA or DMB. That would be ideal and require very little code modifications but impossible as far as I know.

Comment: Why is it impossible? Don't autocreate the datamodules... create the one you need runtime and put a reference in a variable. What have you tried?

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: Use a single DM and switch behaviour at runtime. Thus avoiding code duplication too.

Comment: It's impossible Frazz because each datamodule is unique so can't be referenced by a common variable. How would manually creating the DMs be of any help and what do you mean by "put a reference in a variable"?

@MartynA, I'm using Delphi XE.

David, what do you mean by "switch behaviour at runtime"?

Comment: Ah, ok.  It doesn't make any difference to my answer.  Btw, what did you have in mind in your comment to the other answer when you mention "query objects"?  CDSs are usually populated by SQL executed against server data.  They work fine with result sets from stored procedures, views, user-defined server functions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to drop building your `DataModules` based on specific datasets. Build them using only `TClientDataSet` and write all your code or link all your `DataSources` to these datasets. Then  create other `DataModules` to hold your specific datasets and use your selection method to choose which one to respond as a data provider for the CDS instances. The idea of using an interface to do that is indeed a good one.

This approach will remove all you duplicate code and you will separate business logic (the code that handles the data inside the CDSs) from persistence (the code that transfers data rows from and to the data server).

Comment: I agree that this is a good alternative to what I am suggesting in my answer and it's not mutually exclusive with it - and possibly/probably preferable if the OP doesn't mind the extra work

Comment: I like the idea of TClientDataSets and I was planning to go that route anyway. Unless I'm mistaken though, ClientDataSets are only good for tables. What about query objects?

Comment: @user3640611: a CDS receive its data from a component called `TDatasetProvider`, which receives records from any dataset, tables, queries, or stored procedures. No limitations on that.

Comment: But if a query object is assigned to a CDS you have to change the SQL on the underlying object not the CDS. Here I run into the exact same problem as before: separate code segments for each query change. I don't use any hard-coded SQL queries, all SQL is dynamically created in the software to get specific results.

Comment: @user3640611: well, it depends where you put the code to generate such a SQL code. In the company I work for we have the very same problem. We do like this: Forms have dataware components and presentation logic, *business* DataModules have `TClientDataset` instances and business rules code, *persistence* DataModules have specific kinds of datasets and code to generate the specific SQL that respond to calls from *business* DataModules. Those calls happen by using an interface implemented by the *persistence* DataModules.

Comment: OK I have managed to do this in a crude way since I don't really understand interfaces in relation to DMs. For queries I have added generic functions in the CDS DM that executes SQL in the appropriate DS DM or opens a SQL query in the appropriate DS DM which is then assigned to a corresponding CDS. Any other DS properties or functions CDSs don't have I use a generic function as well. So far it seems to work really well.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to have a global variable or, better, a function or singleton
class or perhaps best of all, an interface, which returns a reference to an abstraction
of what dmA and dmB have in common depending on a boolean flag.  Exactly how to do it,
though, would benefit from some careful thought, most of which you will need to
do yourself because only you know the details of your project and its requirements.

However, there are a few potential issues with it that I think are likely to lead you
towards an implementation like one now-deleted comment suggested, that does away with
datamodules (or hides them away) and uses custom DB objects or interfaces instead to
provide consumer access from forms, reports, etc.

One big issue is to do with the way object visibility works in Delphi + its IDE.

Consider a project which has a unit MyForm1u which is to be a consumer of your DB objects.
and units dmAu and dmBu which contain DB components that you've added via the IDE designer,
that may have the same names in both units but can be of different instance types.

Now, MyForm1u can certainly use dmAu and dmBu, but that has the problem that the DB components
in dmA and dmB are necessarily of published visibility (because that's what needs to
be the case for them to be streamable and IDE-designable).  So, although you could have a function which returns (an instance of) dmA or dmB, if MyForm1u Uses dmAu and dmBu, there's nothing enforce
encapsulation of them so that access to them goes only via that function.

What you *could* do is to define a common ancestor datamodule, call it dmCA in unit
dmCAu and then descend dmA and dmB from it - this would be a bit fiddly to do after the fact
because if dmA and dmB already exist, you would need to hand-edit their DFM files
to adjust component ancestry if you wanted to have some components on dmCA instead.  But
starting anew, you could easily create a new dmCA in your project, containing any DB
components in common between dmA and dmB *which are of the same instance type*, and then descend dmA and dmB from it in the IDE.

This would give you a project structure in which myFormu1 doesn't Use dmAu or dmBu
directly nor, some would say, dmCA.  A better approach might be to have it Use none
of them but rather a unit X which contains a function returning some class, or better 
interface, which in turn has a group of functions which return references to the 
components of dmA and dmB that they have in common in term of name (actually the important thing is their function within the data model of the datamodule) and ancestral type, e.g.

function MyDataSet1 : TDataSet;

so that it can return the AdoQuery1 of dmA or the SqlQuery1 of dmB, depending on
your boolean flag.

Provided your consumer unit(s) Use only unit X and not dmAu, dmBu or dmCAu, that will
enforce the encapsulation of their contents.

This class- or interface-based approach would preclude "wiring up" consumer objects
like TmyForm1 to DB objects using the usual point 'n click approach courtesy of the
IDE's Object Inspector, but these days many would say that that would be no bad thing.